# Visual Studio 2013 spell checker

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, spell-checking, spelling, misspelling

I have dyslexia and am starting my first collaborative project with other students using the IDE Visual Studio 2013. I fear that my miss spellings may cause errors and annoyance to the rest of the team, so I wish to keep my spelling mistakes to a minimum.

Projects on which I work alone are less of a problem, as if I spell the word wrong I tend to spell it wrong throughout the program in the same way - but I feel I would still get use out of a spell checker for these too.

I have had a google but only found a few plugins, most of which are outdated. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Having dyslexia (and I have it a bit too) is not a prerequisite for using a spell checker. Everyone can make spelling mistakes or typos, so a spell checker should simply be mandatory. It is SO embarrassing if you release commercial software and there are spelling mistakes in the UI. It is also a major problem if you make function libraries for use by others. If the function or property names in objects are spelled incorrectly it is both embarrassing and makes it more difficult to find the wanted method. And worst of all, it may not be possible to fix it because that is a "breaking change".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is this one that has been updated recently: [Visual Studio Spell Checker](https://github.com/EWSoftware/VSSpellChecker)

You can just add it from VS by going to the Extensions.
Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online -> Search box -> Search for Spell Checker

I just tried it out, works well.

Answer (score 6):

If you have ReSharper (highly recommended, but a bit pricey) then I can recommend ReSpeller. Costs only $10 and is completely integrated into ReSharper.

http://etherealcode.com/respeller/

At the same time, I can mention that ReSpeller (at least for the version I have, 2.3 for ReSharper 7.1) has one unfortunate quirk, but it is an option that can fortunately be turned off.

[ReSpeller is unexpectedly accepting "prefered" as correct spelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817076/respeller-is-unexpectedly-accepting-prefered-as-correct-spelling)

Comment: Note that there's also a free version of ReSpeller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Code Analysis/Fxcop rules built into visual studio you could add the following to your ruleset:

- [CA1703: Resource strings should be spelled correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264483.aspx)
- [CA1704: Identifiers should be spelled correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264492.aspx)
- [CA2204: Literals should be spelled correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264488.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too.

I am using this spell checker it is awesome. . .

> https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce
>
> Another spell checker
>
> https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/F9CDA5D8-10AF-4CC6-9D17-207222A3FD13?SRC=VSIDE