# ReSpeller is unexpectedly accepting "prefered" as correct spelling

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, spell-checking

I'm generally very happy with ReSpeller, a $10 spellchecker for ReSharper. But I've just noticed that it is accepting "prefered", which I'd like it to consider to be a spelling mistake. I've looked in these three dictionary files:

```
C:\Users\rp\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.1\Plugins\ReSpeller\dic\en_US.dic
C:\Users\rp\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.1\Plugins\ReSpeller\dic\en_US_custom.dic

C:\Users\rp\AppData\Roaming\ReSpeller\en_US.dic
```

but I can't find "prefered" in any of them. Any idea as to what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, it was an RTFM problem.

From the ReSpeller website:

`If ReSpeller sees an incorrect word it tries to split it into all kinds of word pairs and checks each word in the pair separately. So words like "registrykey" or "wildhoney" will be accepted as correct despite the whole words being absent from the dictionary. This is also customizable option.`

It turns out "prefer" is in the dictionary and "ed" is in the dictionary, so that makes "prefered" an accepted word. But the option can be turned off, so I'll do that and see if that results in too many false positives.

Edit - two days later ...

I can definitely recommend running ReSpeller with that option turned off. It results in a lot of false positives, i.e., words that are incorrectly getting flagged as spelling mistakes, so I need to add them to my user dictionary. BUT, I'm also seeing an embarrassingly large number of misspelled words that ReSpeller was previously accepting. Ouch.